# AVAudioPlayer pause() not behaving as expected

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am seeing this unexpected behavior with pause() function of AVAudioPlayer. When I click on 'Pause' button the audio should actually pause at the current time and resume from it when play() is called. But here, when I hit pause() the audio is paused and when I click on play() the audio is playing from the beginning. pause() is behaving like stop().

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBAction func PlayPauseAudioButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.currentImage == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "play-btn") {
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause-btn"), for: .normal)

        do {
            let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "aug-ps-raj", ofType: "mp3")
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
        } catch {
            // Catch the error
        }
        player.play()

    } else {
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "play-btn"), for: .normal)
        player.pause()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you’re creating a new player instance every time play button is clicked. Instead you can create that `AVAudioPlayer` instance  in advance and only call play() and pause() in your button click handler.